# Inserting text inside the image using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am generating a qrcode for each Ticket object using the PIL library and [python-qrcode package](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode). Mostly I was following [this tutorial](http://blog.matael.org/writing/python-and-qrcodes/). Here the author has inserted text inside the qrcode.

[image]

How can I achieve the same effect with the above library? Actually what I want to do is place a text (Ticket show id) below the qrcode, something like this:

```
------------|
|           |
|           |
|           |
|___________|

Seat id: 23c
Show id: 250
```

Right now, this is how I am creating the qrcode:

```
class MovieTicket(models.Model):
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    purchased_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    qrcode = models.ImageField(upload_to='qrcode', blank=True, null=True)
    qrcode_data = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=str(time()).replace('.', '_'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.show and self.seat and self.user and self.purchased_at:
            self.qrcode_data = str(self.user.mobile) + '_' + str(self.show.id) + '_' + str(self.seat.id) + '_' + str(
                time()).replace('.', '_')
            qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=None, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H, box_size=10, border=4)
            qr.add_data(self.qrcode_data)
            qr.make(fit=True)
            img = qr.make_image()
            buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
            img.save(buffer)
            filebuffer = InMemoryUploadedFile(
                buffer, None, self.qrcode_data + '.jpg', 'image/jpg', buffer.len, None)
            self.qrcode = filebuffer
        super(MovieTicket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is it even possible to achieve how I want it to be?

Comment: Have you even looked at the documentation? There's an example in [`ImageDraw`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text)

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but I was actually wondering if it was possible with python-qrcode library. Sorry I was not being clear.